# how to check particular windows service is running using

Tags: java

I have a requirement to check if the given windows service say "XYZService" is running fine.

I understand that we can issue a "sc query " command and check the status of it, windows command prompt.

but I don't know how to do in java.

I am using JDK1.6 in my application.

appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

below is the correct code for verifying service!

```
     Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("sc query "+nameOfService);
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(process.getInputStream(), "UTF-8");
    while(reader.hasNextLine())
        if(reader.nextLine().contains(serviceNAME))
            return true;
    return false;
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
public boolean isProcessRunning(final String processName) throws Exception{
    final Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("tasklist");
    final Scanner reader = new Scanner(process.getInputStream(), "UTF-8");
    while(reader.hasNextLine())
        if(reader.nextLine().startsWith(processName))
            return true;
    return false;
}
```

Note: With the method above, you have to enter the exact process name (case sensitive).
Here is what the table looks like:

[image]

Comment: Excellent @Josh M, it means if the service is not running it will not show up, tasklist will only show running?

Comment: @mahesh Correct : ) Tasklist only shows active service and processes.

Comment: after testing this, it is only searching for windows currently running process and not Services !

Answer (score 0):

With the help of ProcessBuilder we can launch the command prompt(in background) and fetch the status of service.

```
Process process = new ProcessBuilder("C:\\Windows\\System32\\sc.exe", "query", 
serviceName).start(); //serviceName is the name of the service.
InputStream is = process.getInputStream();
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);

String resultLine;
String consoleOutput = "";

while ((resultLine = br.readresultLine()) != null) {
    consoleOutput += resultLine + "\n";
}

if (consoleOutput.contains("STATE")) {
    if (consoleOutput.contains("RUNNING")) {
        // Service is Running...!!
    } else {
        // Service is Not Running...!!
    }
} else {
    // Service Not Found..!!
}
```